# Virtualbox Ubuntu on Windows host appears to be connected to network, but not

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox-networking

I always have so much trouble with networking in Virtualbox. I just created an Ubuntu 14.04 Virtualbox instance under Windows 10. I'm using the default NAT configuration.

[image]

I appear to be connected based on icon at top right, but can't reach the internet.

[image]

**Edit:** My interfaces file is:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: What happen if you use the bridged connector? It should be simpler to be setup. Can you post the content of your `/etc/resolve.conf` file? thx

Comment: `nameserver 129.0.1.1`. So, I'm not even trying to install yet. I'm just doing the live disk "Try Ubuntu" at this point. I'd rather get the networking thing worked out before installing.

Comment: Is is *not connected* or just unable to resolve names? can you `ping 8.8.8.8` for example?

Comment: That pings. As does localhost.

Comment: Try to ping 129.0.1.1 and give the output please

Comment: @TungTran pings fine. `64 bytes from 127.0.1.1 icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.07ms`

Comment: Did you try to switch to bridged connector? It will automatically assign to your VM an ipaddress "compatible" with your LAN, currently it seems you are using a privat IP address, that I guess don't match with your LAN gateway and netmask

Comment: I had tried bridged connector, but no go. But I just tried it again, and selected my wireless card rather than ethernet card, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cant ping www.google.com but you can ping 8.8.8.8, it seems like you cant resolve domain names. You should try different DNS-server. Try 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 DNS-servers. Using bridged connection mode can also help.

Comment: I had tried bridged connector, but not even able to connect to the card (no up and down arrows). So I tried specifying the wireless card rather than the ethernet card in the network configuration, and now it works!